# Confidence interval for unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am stuck trying to solve this problem. I can only get to a certain point in my attempts. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am given the following sample of size $10$ drawn from a $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$-distributed population:

$$(100.4, 99.2, 98.4, 99.6, 103.6, 101.6, 103.2, 99.2, 97.6, 99.2)$$

1. Determine the $95 \%$ confidence interval for the **unknown expected value** $\mu$ and **known variance** $\sigma^2=4$
2. Determine the $95 \%$ confidence interval for the **unknow expected value** $\mu$ and **unknown variance** $\sigma^2$
3. Determine the $95\%$ confidence interval for the **unkown variance** $\sigma^2$ and **unknown expected value** $\mu$

**What I have tried so far (with some resources from the web):**

1. $$\alpha=1-0.95=0.05\\ \Phi(c)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=0.975$$

The mean of the sample is: $$\bar{X}=\frac{1002}{10}=100.2$$

Then I can use the following formula: $$\bar{X}-c \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\le \mu \le \bar{X}+c \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

I know $\bar{X}=100.2, \sigma=2,n=10$ but how can I find $c$?

2. For question two, is it just the exact same calculation as 1. but now using the sample variance?
3. What is the difference to question 2. ? Aren't they the same?

Comment: 2 and 3 are the same.    Edit error?  For 2 be careful in getting the sample variance. (Divide by 9, not 10).

Comment: You can find $c$ by using either a [normal distribution table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) or [software](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%5BZ%3Ez%5D+%3D+0.90). It requires calculating the inverse of the [standard normal cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) ($\Phi$).

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thanks for the hint. So my approach is correct? Isn't the third one asking me to find the confidence interval for the variance vs for the mean. I checked again and the thrid question is worded exactly like that. The way I would have maybe interpreted it is "the variance is in what interval with $95 \%$ confidence" vs. "the mean is in what interval with $95 \%$ confidence" for question 2.  Could that be?

Comment: @Nullspace I think you're right with that interpretation of the difference between 2 and 3, 2 is asking for the confidence interval of the mean, 3 is asking for the confidence interval of the variance. Though the "and" is kind of weird in both statements.

Comment: My interpretation of 2 and 3 is that the word 'and' makes them both the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part 1, for $95\%$ confidence interval concerning normal distribution, the confidence coefficient $c$ is usually taken to be $1.96$. Of course, as pointed out by Amaan in the comment, a normal distribution table or software could be helpful.

I am not sure what is the exact difference between 2 and 3, but the main difference here is that $\sigma^2$ is unknown. In that case, you should use the sample variance $$s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$ to present an estimate of $\sigma^2$. In that case, you should know that $$\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{s^2/n}}\sim t_{n-1}.$$ Thus a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\mu$ is given by $$\bar{X}-t_{n-1,0.975}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{n}}<\mu<\bar{X}+t_{n-1,0.975}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{n}}.$$ Here $t_{n-1,0.975}$ is the $97.5\%$ quantile of [$t$-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with degree of freedom $n-1$. Note that $t$-distribution is also symmetric (Similar to normal distribution $t_{n-1,0.025}=-t_{n-1,0.975}$), so totally $0.025\cdot 2=0.05$ of probability is excluded.

On the other hand, note that $$\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi_{n-1}^2,$$ where $\chi_{n-1}^2$ is the [chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) of degree of freedom $n-1$. Again, let $\chi_{n-1,0.025}^2$ and $\chi_{n-1,0.975}^2$ be the $2.5\%$ and $97.5\%$ quantiles of such distribution, resp. Then a $95\%$ CI is given as follows: $$\chi_{n-1,0.025}^2<\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2}<\chi_{n-1,0.975}^2\implies\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi_{n-1,0.975}^2}<\sigma^2<\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi_{n-1,0.025}^2}.$$

For more about this, I recommend you to check the [online lecture notes](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/4/4.1) here.

Comment: This really helped me and thanks for the link!